# Why synonyms are not working in this example

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my code

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index" -d '
{
"settings" : {
"analysis"  : {
"filter" : {
"my_synonym_filter" : {
"type" : "synonym",
"synonyms" : [
"luck,love"
]
}
},
"analyzer" : {
" my_synonym_filter " : {
"tokenizer" : "standard",
"filter" : [
"lowercase",
"my_synonym_filter"
]
}}}}}'


curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping/doc?pretty" -d '
{
"properties" : {
"description" : {
"type" : "string",
"fields" : {
"ss" : {
"type" : "string",
"analyzer" : " my_synonym_filter "
}}}}}'


curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index/doc/1" -d '
{
"description" : "luck is the best in the world"
}
'


curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index/doc/2" -d '
{
"description" : "luck is just wonderful"
}
'
```

as you see i created two synonyms words `luck` and `love` with a custom analyzer

but when i do this query

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty" -d '
{
"query" : {
"match" : {
"description" : "love" 
}
}
}
'
```

I got no results, though the love is a synonyms for luck

why please? what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you resolve your problem in the end?

Comment: @CrnaStena yes than you, your solution works

Comment: Great. Do you mind upvoting and/or marking it as answer?

Comment: @CrnaStena sorry I can't upvote because i don't have 15 points (the minimum required), but i accepted it

Comment: Thanks man. Welcome to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @BrookeB but would like to add two more things:

> 1. Your filter and analyzer have same name which could be confusing. I renamed analyzer to "**my_analyzer**"
> 2. If you are defining **multi_field** declare it as such.

Here is full example that works for me:

```
# combined settings and mappings in one call
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index3" -d '
{
    "settings" : 
    {
        "analysis"  : 
        {
            "filter" : 
            {
                "my_synonym_filter" : 
                {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "synonyms" : [ "luck,love" ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer" : 
            {
                "my_analyzer" : 
                {
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "filter" : [
                        "lowercase",
                        "my_synonym_filter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties" : {
                "description" : {
                    "type" : "multi_field",
                    "fields" : {
                        "ss" : {
                            "type" : "string",
                            "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
    }
}'

# check the analyzer
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_index3/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty" -d 'luck is the best in the world'

# doc 1
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index3/doc/1" -d '
{
"description.ss" : "luck is the best in the world"
}
'

# doc 2, you can put to the property field
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index3/doc/2" -d '
{
"description.ss" : "luck is just wonderful"
}
'

# doc 3, you can put directly to the property, but...
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index3/doc/3" -d '
{
"description" : "love conquors all"
}
'

# gets no documents
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/my_index3/_search?pretty" -d '
{
"query" : {
"match" : {
"description" : "love" 
}
}
}
'

# gets all 3 documents
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/my_index3/_search?pretty" -d '
{
"query" : {
"match" : {
"description.ss" : "love" 
}
}
}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have created "description" as multi-field in your mapping, and only applied your custom analyzer to the "ss" part.

Try running the same query against the  "description.ss" field to see if you get the results you are expecting.

Comment: Also remove the spaces in the analyzer name (e.g. `"my_synonym_filter"` instead of `" my_synonym_filter "`) as that might create unwanted bugs.